# Magento 2 Cron job not running with constructor

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I am currently developing a drop shipping module for our `Magento 2.2.3` store.

For this I am creating a cron job to send a post request to my API that pulls in all the orders where a Magento 2 order hasn't been created. The cron job will then create magento 2 orders for these.

I have created a cron job that pulls orders to our database. this is working without a problem. The second cron job must then Create the orders.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\DropShippingreceiver\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CreateNewOrders {
protected $logger;
protected $_resource;
protected $curlClient;
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
  LoggerInterface $logger,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
  \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
  \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
  \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
  \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService
) {
    $this->curlClient = $curl;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_product = $product;
    $this->_formkey = $formkey;
    $this->quote = $quote;
    $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->orderService = $orderService;
}

 public function execute() {
  $this->logger->info("Creating new Orders-----------------------------");

  //Pull uncreated orders from DB. foreach( uncreated order) { create order }
//All other contents of this method have been commented out while testing.
//The only lines that i want to run are the two shown in this method: 
//Log "finished creating" & Log "Creating new"

  $this->logger->info("Finished Creating new Orders---------------------");
 }
}
```

If i only add the Inject the following dependencies into the constructor, the cron job runs fine with no problems.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
LoggerInterface $logger,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
```

However, when i add the other dependencies, the Cron refuses to run at all.

Is there an issue with cron jobs regarding adding too many dependencies?
I require all of these to create an order programatically, to my understanding.

Although i mention creating orders, i am not asking how to do this as i already have the code set up for it.

**'Why will my Cron job not run when i add the extra dependencies?'** all i am trying to make it do for now is output to the logger.

Thanks

EDIT:

When i run the cron, this gets logged to the system.log and debug.log

```
[2018-06-08 10:36:06] main.INFO: Too late for the schedule Schedule Id: 37125 Job Code: dropshipping_createorders [] []
[2018-06-08 10:36:06] main.INFO: Too late for the schedule Schedule Id: 37128 Job Code: dropshipping_createorders [] []
```

Comment: Please share code which is in this method : ` public function execute() {
  $this->logger->info("Creating new Orders-----------------------------");

  //Pull uncreated orders from DB. foreach( uncreated order) { create order }

  $this->logger->info("Finished Creating new Orders---------------------");
 }`

Comment: you have used `$this->logger` you must need `LoggerInterface $logger,`

Comment: That is all the code in that method for now, i only want it to output to log. I just want the Cron to run with these dependencies

Comment: the logger is not the issue, when i only add the first 4 dependencies, the Cron runs absolutely fine

Comment: that is in first four, if you will remove those you must run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: I have run all of the necassary commands multiple times setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, cache clean, cache flush, cron:run, setup:cron:install

Comment: ok now delete this only : `\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,` and this `$this->curlClient = $curl;
    $this->_resource = $resource;` now just run di compile and try again.

Comment: I need these dependencies in order to get all the uncreated orders and create new Magento orders for them, i cannot do this if i delete those lines

Comment: it will run in next cron schedule. you can check that in `cron_schedule`  table

Comment: i have been watching the `cron_schedule` table and the cron still refuses to run

Comment: I have tested your code working fine try after delete all crons from that table.

Comment: is it working for you?

Comment: no, unfortunately it still will not run with all the dependencies add.

i am instead trying to create a model which will inject the necessary dependencies to create the order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78636/discussion-between-kunj-and-vmp).